# Where to put worker files for ti.worker Titanium module?

Tags: module, titanium, worker

I have the module installed but I can't figure where in the project my worker.js file should go. This is an Alloy project and I have tried putting the file in a few different places.

I pared my worker down to this for testing:

```
worker.addEventListener('message', function(event){
   worker.postMessage('complete');
});
```

I keep getting this error:

```
The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.
[DEBUG] Reason:
[DEBUG] *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
[DEBUG] Stack trace:
[DEBUG] 0   CoreFoundation                      0x03475012 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
[DEBUG] 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03082e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
[DEBUG] 2   CoreFoundation                      0x03474deb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
[DEBUG] 3   Foundation                          0x00cb0281 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 94
[DEBUG] 4   Foundation                          0x00cb020b +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 67
[DEBUG] 5   Swap-A-Doodle                       0x00046259 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 265
[DEBUG] 6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03096705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
[DEBUG] 7   Swap-A-Doodle                       0x0004bbd1 -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 145
[DEBUG] 8   Swap-A-Doodle                       0x0004e108 -[KrollContext invokeOnThread:method:withObject:callback:selector:] + 248
[DEBUG] 9   Swap-A-Doodle                       0x00046a9d -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 125
[DEBUG] 10  Swap-A-Doodle                       0x000479b1 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 2657
[DEBUG] 11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030966b0 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
[DEBUG] 12  Swap-A-Doodle                       0x0004f0ef -[KrollContext main] + 3199
[DEBUG] 13  Foundation                          0x00ce40d5 -[NSThread main] + 76
[DEBUG] 14  Foundation                          0x00ce4034 __NSThread__main__ + 1304
[DEBUG] 15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x977a1ed9 _pthread_start + 335
[DEBUG] 16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x977a56de thread_start + 34
[DEBUG] 2013-01-30 19:10:35.372 Swap-A-Doodle[24095:1da0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
[DEBUG] *** First throw call stack:
[DEBUG] (0x3475012 0x3082e7e 0x3474deb 0xcb0281 0xcb020b 0x46259 0x3096705 0x4bbd1 0x4e108 0x46a9d 0x479b1 0x30966b0 0x4f0ef 0xce40d5 0xce4034 0x977a1ed9 0x977a56de)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with SDK 2.1+ with no planned fix. https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.worker/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `app/lib`, all the files in `app/lib` will be put in the base of the generated `Resources/` directory so you can access worker.js like this in whatever controller you are using to instantiate the worker:

```
var worker = require('ti.worker');

// create a worker thread instance
var task = worker.createWorker('worker.js');
task.postMessage({
   msg:'Hello'
});
```

This *should* post the message to your worker.js file. Haven't tested it though, good luck!

Comment: I have tried that but I got the same error described above. Here is a demo https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiWorkerExample